# add colorstop dynamically in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I have been working on this for about a week now and I still have no idea of how to DYNAMICALLY add a colorstop to a gradient fill.

I can fill an object with a gradient fill, but how do I add a new colorstop to it after it has been created?

```
    circle.setGradient('fill', 
    {
        type: 'linear',
        x1: 0,
        y1: -circle.height / 2,
        x2: 0,
        y2: circle.height / 2,
        colorStops: 
        {
            0: '#000',
            1: '#f00'
         }
    });
    canvas.add(circle);
```

Assuming I have the above code, how can I add a third colorStop (e.g. 0.5: 'blue') dynamically, after the fill has been created?

Help?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a way to do what I want. Thanks.